# Why doesn't this specific syntax work for upserting?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, upsert

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I want to synchronize two tables which have the same definition but exist in different databases. MERGE INTO only exists in 2008 and I'd prefer a syntax where I don't have to specify columns in the UPDATE. So I stumbled upon [various posts](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/24/merge-command/) using the following syntax:

```
UPDATE Destination FROM (Source INTERSECT Destination)
INSERT INTO Destination FROM (Source EXCEPT Destination)
```

But when I try to execute it I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

How can I get this working? I have multiple tables which I need to synchronize and I don't want to specify all the columns in every statement.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: If you don't specify columns, how is the update to know what to apply to what, from where?

Comment: @Andrew Barber: I'm aware of that, was never talking about INSERT--just UPDATE statements.

Comment: @OMG Ponies : I have no idea why I read 'UPDATE' as if it said 'INSERT'. My bad!!!

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I don't think that would be a problem in this specific scenario where the two tables are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Books Online the [`update` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177523%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) requires the `set` keyword, and it must come before the optional `from` keyword. The [`insert` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174335%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) doesn't have a stand alone `from` keyword, the `from` only exists as part of a `select` statement either as a derived table source or within a common table expression.

The link you reference is not showing valid SQL Server 2005 syntax.

"How can I get this working? I have multiple tables which I need to synchronize and I don't want to specify all the columns in every statement."

For `update`, you must specify all the columns. For `insert` if the source and destination have the same struture then you can use `insert into TARGTET_TABLE_NAME select * from SOURCE_TABLE_NAME` **BUT** that is not recommended for production code, if the source or destination change, the statement would break. If source and destination differ, then you must specify columns on at least one side of the insert.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably generate the statements from the meta information in the system tables. That way I can also check if the structure of the tables is really identical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this doesn't answer your question, but assuming the whole reason for this is in the interest of saving time, can't you just right-click the source table and generate the INSERT script, then right-click the destination table and generate a blank SELECT script, then combine the two?  This will only work if a kill-and-fill is acceptable in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that won't work here. There are a lot of relationships between the tables (and not all are to be synchronized) so I can't just empty them. Also it would kill the possibility to add columns without having to change code/config.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and that's why we use redgate SQLCompare and DataCompare for data synchronizing - it generates and runs the scripts for us!  Here's a similar/duplicate SO post to browse through and see if you can get ideas from:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344970/tsql-identity-insert-without-column-name-list

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.